# Traefik with docker-compose, LetsEncrypt, and multiple domains

Tags: docker, docker-compose, reverse-proxy, traefik

I'm trying to do a run a ghost image through `docker-compose` using traefik as the reverse proxy.

I have two domains, `sub.foo.com` and `bar.com`. After `docker-compose up -d` is called, the container is accessible via `sub.foo.com:2386` but not `bar.com`. I know it's not necessary to have the `ports` option in the `ghost.service`, but have it there to prove the container comes up.

Here's my configuration:

---

**traefik.toml**

```
debug = false

logLevel = "ERROR"
defaultEntryPoints = ["https","http"]

[entryPoints]

[entryPoints.http]
address = ":80"
[entryPoints.http.redirect]
entryPoint = "https"

[entryPoints.https]
address = ":443"
  [entryPoints.https.tls]

[retry]

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "sub.foo.com"
watch = true
exposedbydefault = false

[acme]
email = "john.doe@example.com"
storage = "acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
onHostRule = true
[acme.httpChallenge]
entryPoint = "http"
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    networks:
      - ghost
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: testing
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ghost
      MYSQL_USER: ghost
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ghost
  ghost:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: ghost:2.1.2-alpine
    ports:
      - "2368:2368"
    networks:
      - traefik
      - ghost
    volumes:
      - ghost_data:/var/lib/ghost/content
    environment:
      database__client: mysql
      database__connection__host: db
      database__connection__user: ghost
      database__connection__password: ghost
      database__connection__database: ghost
    labels:
      - "traefik.backend=ghost"
      - "traefik.docker.network=traefik"
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:bar.com"
      - "traefik.port=2368"
      - "traefik.protocol=http"

volumes:
  db_data: {}
  ghost_data: {}

networks:
  ghost: {}
  traefik:
    external: true
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? My DNS records are pointed identically on `sub.foo.com` and `bar.com`. When I navigate to `bar.com` I end up with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Access Denied</title>
<style type="text/css">body {margin:0;font-family:verdana,sans-serif;} h1 {margin:0;padding:12px 25px;background-color:#343434;color:#ddd} p {margin:12px 25px;} strong {color:#E0042D;}</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Access Denied</h1>
<p>
<strong>You are attempting to access a forbidden site.</strong><br/><br/>
Consult your system administrator for details.
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

which is not your standard traefik error. Is something not binding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps it got cut off but the following is also needed in your toml:

```
...
[acme]
email = "john.doe@example.com"
storage = "acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
onHostRule = true
[[acme.domains]]
  main = "bar.com"
[acme.httpChallenge]
  entryPoint = "http"
```

Your docker-compose might be missing the following:

```
labels:
  ....
  - "traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http,https"
```

The error however looks like something different not treafik related. Is treafik exposed to port 80 and 443 on your server?

Comment: The `entryPoints` and cache clearing on my browser fixed it, thanks for your help!